# history texts or texts in history class?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

In the context of the title of a paper, what would you choose: "Reading causal texts in history class (classroom)" or "Reading causal history texts" ?

Comment: Is the location important to the paper?

Comment: Hi, not really, no. The important elements are the paper, that they are causal and happen in the context of history classes at school.

Comment: When I asked the question, I was equating “location” with “In the classroom” which does seem to be important to you. “The use of causal history texts in the classroom”

Comment: I just want the context of education to appear in the phrase, not necessarily the location. So it could be "class" or "classroom". In fact, the question could be: Would it be clear enough if I wrote "history text" only? It did sound a little awkward to me, hence my question.

Comment: No, any book on history would be a history text.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, both titles could be used but the meaning conveyed would be different. In the first case, it seems that any type of content -providing it is 'casual'- would be acceptable: news, tales, etc. However, in the second case, the only type of text to be read would be have to be about history.

Comment: But in the first, the reading takes place in the context of a class, while the second says nothing about an educational context.

Comment: Correct. I had assumed that the context would also be the classroom, but you are absolutely right, which brings about one more difference and makes both titles a little more different.